# Get Column value from DataGridRow in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I'm creating a WPF application in which when a user clicks on a Row of the DataGrid, I need to  take a Column value and using that value I need to get data from Database.

I'm able to Find the DataGridRow but unable to get the column values. Here is my code ...

```
DataGridRow BillRow = sender as DataGridRow;
```

I get the selected row details into BillRow (I'm able to see them in Visualiser) but unable to  get the values into a variable. Can you help me ??

Comment: > Can you help me - data binding will help you. :) It is hard to work without it in WPF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution may be help you

```
 public static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid, int row, int column)
    {
        DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dataGrid, row);
        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

            // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
                dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dataGrid.Columns[column]);

                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            }

            return cell;
        }

        return null;
     }
```